# Is there an API for Coffee Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm creating a Coffee related iOS app and as a side-feature I would like to allow users to read, ask and answer questions on Coffee.StackExchange from the application.

Of course I would make it very clear in the app that coffee.stackexchange.com is an external site not owned by myself.

### Question

Is there a way to do this? If it's not possible to ask and answer, I'd like to at least be able to get a read-only feed.

Comment: Hey, Please share your App link when its out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) is available for your use. It supports both read and write operations. Passing the site parameter `site=coffee`  is all you need to direct them to this particular site.

[Sample query](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=creation&site=coffee&filter=!9YdnSIN18): returns 10 newest questions on the site.